# can't send email to masking domain in Office 365

Tags: exchange, domain, outlook, microsoft-office-365

i have some issue here.
first i have office 365 and domain xxx.com . im already masking office 365 xx.onmicrosoft.com with my domain xxx.com.
here are my MX Record :  https://prnt.sc/ti1kqr
i can't send email to user@xxx.com from other email account, but i can send if the address email to user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com

if something setting i miss?

thankyou

Comment: Does `user@xxx.com` actually have that email address? What happens when you email `user@xxx.com`?

Comment: hello @joeqwerty, i think i have it, cause i can login office 365 account usinguser@xxx.com
thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. How long after creating the MX record? It may take some time to take effect. You could test it using http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx
2. Make sure the mailbox is existing, you could use user@domain.com to login Office 365 OWA: Outlook.office365.com/owa
3. Did other user have the same issue? This can help use isolate whether this is mailbox issue.
4. Did the sender get NDR?

You could test “Inbound SMTP Email” of https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/o365 to get more information.

Comment: hello Jayce,
let me answer one by one.

1. before i realise i couldn't send email to user@xxx.com it have been 1 week after masking domain office 365. here the screenshoot for the MX check : http://prntscr.com/tinku1and http://prntscr.com/tinm14

2. the mailbox is existing, cause i could send email to user@xxx.onmicorosoft.com

3. yes, all users have same issue

4. no, sender doesn't get NDR

Comment: Please  test “Inbound SMTP Email” of https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/o365

Comment: hi  Jayce, here the screenshoot :  http://prntscr.com/tirwhr all green

Comment: update, im noticing that my office 365 only block/doesn't receive email from domain abc.com , the case is same i can only send an email from abc.com into xxx.onmicrosoft.om not xxx.com

Comment: Since the test in EXRCA passes, I think this issue may be related to the specific domain configuration. 
“im noticing that my office 365 only block/doesn't receive email from domain abc.com” it works when we send message from other public domain, such as Hotmail/Gmail? So I want to confirm if the xxx.com and abc.com are host in same mail server? For Exchange organization, it is called accepted domain.

Comment: Hi Jayce, 
i found the problem. about your question, before my domain xxx.com i use for masking in office 365 im adding the domain in the same domain with abc.com. after using xxx.com for masking office 365 im forgot to delete xxx.com in hosting abc,com.
now im already delete it and work fine. Thankyou

Comment: I am glad to know this issue is resolved.